# Nerve of functor between small categories is an inner Kan fibration?

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

Let's say if $u:C\to D$ is a functor between small categories. I am wondering why the nerve $$N(c):N(C)\to N(D)$$ becomes an inner Kan fibration?

An inner Kan fibration is a morphism with the right lifting property with respect to the inclusion of inner horns.

I feel like it should be obvious so I must have missed something. Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: In a sense, because composition in a 1-category is unique. But you could just show that the left adjoint of the nerve functor sends inner horn inclusions to isomorphisms.

Comment: @ZhenLin How would the former statement help? Also, do you mind sharing a link about the latter statement on the isomorphism between inner horn and $\Delta^n$? I know that the nerve functor has a left adjoint by Kan's theorem.

Comment: You can write out what it means to give a filler for an inner horn very explicitly in terms of simplices and equations involving face operators. Combine that with the definition of nerve to see that fillers automatically exist and are unique.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thank you so much for your answer! Also, would you please share some references on this topic? I struggled a lot with the lecturer's note as it skips steps too often.